# Hyperledger fabric 1.4 ./byfn.sh up is giving error when peer0_Org2 connecting to channel

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to build 3 Organisations of which , Org1 and Org2 has 1 node and Org3 has 4 nodes. i am using the same architecture as byfn.sh file. I have added extras for making the third organisation. When i run ./byfn.sh up it gives the following error.

```
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org2.example.com:9051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 172.28.0.2:9051: connect: connection refused"
peer0.org2 failed to join the channel, Retry after 10 seconds
```

I am new to hyperledger fabric. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

My Configtx.yaml file:

```
Organizations:
    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2
        Name: Org2MSP

        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp


        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 7051
    - &Org3

        Name: Org3MSP
        ID: Org3MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin', 'Org3MSP.peer', 'Org3MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin', 'Org3MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org3.example.com
              Port: 7051
Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
         V1_4_2: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
      V1_4_2: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_4_2: true
        V1_3: false
        V1_2: false
        V1_1: false
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: solo
    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
      Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
    ThreeOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Docker-compose-cli.yaml file:

```
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - SYS_CHANNEL=$SYS_CHANNEL
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer0.org3.example.com
      - peer1.org3.example.com
      - peer2.org3.example.com
      - peer3.org3.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

docker-compose-base.yaml file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0 # 0.0.0.0 it means it can listen to any ip-address in the network. If you want ordere to listen to specific ip address, you can override the same here.
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file  # file= indicates the genesis file we are using is a file system
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    volumes:
        - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050 # see the web page

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051  #https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/defining_peer_for_multiple/19199485?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,19199485
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051    #if you only have 1 peer per org, you don't need a bootstrap config. 
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:8052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production

    ports:
      - 8051:8051

  peer0.org3.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org3.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org3.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org3.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org3.example.com:9052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org3.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org3.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org3.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 9051:9051

  peer1.org3.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org3.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org3.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org3.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org3.example.com:10052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org3.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer2.org3.example.com:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org3.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org3.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org3.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 10051:10051

  peer2.org3.example.com:
    container_name: peer2.org3.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer2.org3.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer2.org3.example.com:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:11051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer2.org3.example.com:11052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:11052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer2.org3.example.com:11051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer3.org3.example.com:12051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer2.org3.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer2.org3.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer2.org3.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 11051:11051

  peer3.org3.example.com:
    container_name: peer3.org3.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer3.org3.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer3.org3.example.com:12051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:12051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer3.org3.example.com:12052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:12052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer3.org3.example.com:12051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org3.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer3.org3.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer3.org3.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer3.org3.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 12051:12051
```

When i write ./byfn.sh up, i get this error.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                      NAMES
bc89f3e6ad9c        hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     "/bin/bash"         3 seconds ago       Up Less than a second                                 cli
385652e2b469        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   13 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds               0.0.0.0:8051->8051/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
6712c3fc4dcf        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   13 seconds ago      Exited (1) 5 seconds ago                              peer1.org3.example.com
ecb198db73aa        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           13 seconds ago      Up 7 seconds               0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp     orderer.example.com
be9e0d491f63        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   13 seconds ago      Up 3 seconds               0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
2639c5d85bd2        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   13 seconds ago      Up 4 seconds               0.0.0.0:12051->12051/tcp   peer3.org3.example.com
5c87eb50608a        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   13 seconds ago      Up 7 seconds               0.0.0.0:11051->11051/tcp   peer2.org3.example.com
1bae906c793c        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   13 seconds ago      Up 5 seconds               0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp     peer0.org3.example.com

Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test

===================== peer0.org1 joined channel 'mychannel' ===================== 

+ peer channel join -b mychannel.block
+ res=1
+ set +x
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org2.example.com:9051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 172.28.0.2:9051: connect: connection refused"
peer0.org2 failed to join the channel, Retry after 10 seconds
```

Please help . Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

In the docker-compose file, you have assigned port `8051` to `peer0.org2` whereas, you are trying to connect to the port `9051`.

Comment: Okay sir, will check on that. Could you please say why is my peer1.org3 container exits after running the code ma'am?  I am getting this error.Thanks again

Comment: You are mounting a folder which doesn't exist  
`-../cryptoconfig/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org3.exampe.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
 - ../cryptoconfig/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org3.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls`


You are finding certificates of org3 inside org2 folder.

Comment: Thank you sir. I corrected those mistakes. Now i am getting this error. ```Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: API error (404): network _byfn not found
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Chaincode instantiation on peer0.org2 on channel 'mychannel' failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
``` Please help me solve this error sir.